# Python: Асинхронные HTTP запросы на N url`s

Tags: python, requests, асинхронность, asyncio, aiohttp

Мне необходимо получить данные с 8 url

**Как я это делаю синхронно:**

```
urls = [
    'example.com',
    'example.com',
    'example.com',
    ...
]

for url in urls:
    req += json.loads(requests.get(url).text)
```

**req - содержит данные с сайта (то, что мне и необходимо)**, все работает как часы, **НО скорость меня не устраивает**, так как таких запросов у меня большое количество будет

Я вспомнил про то что есть **асинхронность, попробовал ее реализовать:**

```
async def fetch_pages(links):
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        results = []
        for link in links:
            async with session.get(link) as resp:
                results += json.loads(await resp.text())
    return results
```

К сожалению, эта функцию не работает шустрее, чем синхронный способ *(понимаю, что это я сделал что то не так)*

Как по моему мнению должен работать мой скрипт:

Даю функции массив с ссылками, он отправляет запросы по этим ссылкам, получает со всех ссылок ответы, и отдает массив с данными обратно

Сама проблема в том, что я не знаю как сделать так, чтобы скрипт сначала отправил запросы, а после ждал того, как получит ответ от всех

Пояснение: синхронный код работал так: отправлял запрос на сайт, ждал получения данных, после отправлял второй запрос, ждал и так далее..

Comment: @insolor вряд ли поможет, скорее всего всё время тратится аа session.get

Comment: Может проще будет попробовать `grequests`, например, тут можно почитать https://habr.com/ru/post/334970/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Идея такая: нужно не дожидаться завершения каждого запроса, а собирать их в список, потом ожидать завершения всех их через [`asyncio.gather`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.gather).

Рабочий прототип такой:

```
import asyncio
import aiohttp
import requests
from time import time


async def fetch(url, session):
    async with session.get(url) as response:
        return await response.text()


async def fetch_pages_sync(links):
    """
    Последовательное скачивание с каждой ссылки
    (дожидаемся скачивания по ссылке, потом переходим к следующей)
    """
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        results = []

        for link in links:
            results.append(await fetch(link, session))
        
        return results



async def fetch_pages_parallel(links):
    """
    Параллельное скачивание с каждой ссылки
    (собираем awitable запросы в список, потом параллельно собираем результат через asyncio.gather)
    """
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        results = []

        for link in links:
            results.append(fetch(link, session))
        
        return await asyncio.gather(*results)


async def main():
    urls = [
        'https://google.com',
    ] * 40


    t = time()
    # print([text[:100] for text in await fetch_pages_sync(urls)])
    result = await fetch_pages_sync(urls)
    print(time() - t)

    t = time()
    # print([text[:100] for text in await fetch_pages_parallel(urls)])
    result = await fetch_pages_parallel(urls)
    print(time() - t)

    t = time()
    with requests.Session() as session:
        for url in urls:
            result = session.get(url).text
    print(time() - t)


asyncio.run(main())
```

Тут `fetch_pages_sync` ожидает завершения каждого запроса, потом переходит к следующему, `fetch_pages_parallel` - ожидает завершения всех их одновременно, для контроля еще добавил гарантированно синхронных запрос через `requests` в цикле.

Замеры по времени:

```
6.519821405410767
0.6476857662200928
7.366809368133545
```

Видим, что второй вариант намного лучше по времени, а первый и третий примерно одинаковы.

Запускал на Python 3.10, Linux Mint 21.1. Код сначала писал с нуля, потом нашел вот эту статью, взял некоторые идеи оттуда: [Making 1 million requests with python-aiohttp](https://pawelmhm.github.io/asyncio/python/aiohttp/2016/04/22/asyncio-aiohttp.html). Обратите внимание на раздел **Testing the limits**: там тестируются 1000 запросов, и все начинает упираться в количество открытых одновременно сокетов.

В `ensure_future`/`create_task` не стал оборачивать, т.к. насколько я помню, `gather` с какой-то версии python сам оборачивает корутины в таски.